# Not able to add Postion(latitude and longitude) type field in Document dynamically in Vespa

Tags: bigdata, vespa

```
DocumentAccess access = DocumentAccess.createDefault();
        DocumentType type = access.getDocumentTypeManager().getDocumentType("location");
 DocumentId id = new DocumentId("id:location:location::4");
        Document document = new Document(type, id);
        document.setFieldValue(document.getDataType().getField("token"), "qwerty");
        **document.setFieldValue(document.getDataType().getField("latlong"),"N28.6273348;E77.4327459");**
        document.setFieldValue(document.getDataType().getField("data_timestamp"), "00:00:00 00:00:00");
```

When adding latlong field of Position type, I am getting this error in search API.

```
"message": "Invalid search request [/search/?query=dcnQ8ar52Y]: Type class com.yahoo.document.datatypes.StringFieldValue can not specify a class com.yahoo.document.datatypes.Struct instance"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `com.yahoo.document.PositionDataType.fromString("N28.6273348;E77.4327459")`

Comment: Thanks Jo.You saved my day. You are great. :)